# r locf multiple columns and group by

Tags: r, locf

My question consists of 2 parts:
First I want to perform a last observation carried forward (or complete) using a data frame similar to the one below. So, missing year / month should be created and subsequently values for X1 and X2 should be carried forward.

```
set.seed(1)
df <- data.frame(year = sort(rep(c(2018,2019),4)),
                 month = c(1,2,5,8,1,2,3,6),
                 X1 = sort(sample(1:100,8)),
                 X2 = sort(sample(1:100,8)))
```

The desired output should be:

```
   year month X1 X2
1  2018     1 20  7
2  2018     2 27 18
3  2018     3 27 18
4  2018     4 27 18
5  2018     5 37 21
6  2018     6 37 21
7  2018     7 37 21
8  2018     8 57 37
9  2018     9 57 37
10 2018    10 57 37
11 2018    11 57 37
12 2018    12 57 37
13 2019     1 62 47
14 2019     2 86 63
15 2019     3 89 66
16 2019     4 89 66
17 2019     5 89 66
18 2019     6 97 73
19 2019     7 97 73
20 2019     8 97 73
21 2019     9 97 73
22 2019    10 97 73
23 2019    11 97 73
24 2019    12 97 73
```

Additionally, I have some variables that I would like to group by. So if I have a variable called 'Group' consisting of values 1 and 2, I want the LOCF described above to be performed for both groups separately.

Answer (score 0):

The seed returns different data for me but I think what you are trying to do is combination of `complete` and `fill`

```
library(tidyr)
df %>% complete(year, month = 1:12) %>% fill(X1, X2)
```

Comment: Thanks! This works for the example I posted but my actual data frame has much more variables and the result of your solution is identical to the data frame i used for input (so before and after are the same). Do you have a solution for this? Also, do you have a suggestion for the grouping issue i posted at the end?

Comment: @Joep_S Not sure if I completely understand. If you have many columns to fill you can use `fill(everything())` and you need to assign the result back. You can also fill by group.  Try `df1 <- df %>% complete(year, month = 1:12) %>% group_by(group_column) %>% fill(everything())` then check `df1`. If it doesn't work it would be helpful if you could share data using dput where we can reproduce the same issue that you are facing.